# Picker not populating correctly after it has been set once and cleared

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have a few different pickers that are used to select options related to inputting a transaction. I provide the user with a way to have preset templates they can press that will populate the pickers automatically.

Here is some code for one of my pickers that I'm having issues with. This picker works fine when selecting a category manually.

```
Picker("Category", selection: $category, content: {
                        ForEach(user.categories, id: \.self) { category in
                            Text(category.name)
                                .tag(category as Category?)
                        }
                    })
```

There is a picker that is used for the templates themselves. When the user selects a template, it uses the `onChange` to populate the other pickers. `savedTransaction` is the template. I was using a different name previously, and didn't update it.

```
.onChange(of: savedTransaction, perform: { value in
                        if savedTransaction != nil {
                            //set fields
                            type = savedTransaction!.transaction.type
                            
                            if type == .expense {
                                category = savedTransaction!.transaction.category
                                
                                if savedTransaction!.transaction.subcategory != nil {
                                    subcategory = savedTransaction!.transaction.subcategory
                                }
                            }
                            
                            amount = savedTransaction!.transaction.amount
                            
                            if savedTransaction!.transaction.note != nil {
                                
                                note = savedTransaction!.transaction.note!
                            }
                            
                        }
                    })
```

Once a user has selected a template, they can add the transaction. Some stuff is ran to add the transaction and then the fields are cleared with this code.

```
//Clear fields
savedTransaction = nil
date = Date()
type = .income
category = nil
subcategory = nil
amount = 0.0
note = ""
```

This work fine the first time the user does it. After that, when they select the same template, the "Category" picker will not populate anymore.

```
category = savedTransaction!.transaction.category
```

I ran `print(category)` after the line you see above, and the category will be set correctly, however, the picker itself will not show that. You have to manually select the category to make it show. What would cause the picker to not show what is selected, even though `category` isn't nil? Please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT: Added this code but found that this works as expected. It should be similar to what I'm doing in my application. I'm trying to find the difference now. Template is the same as SavedTransaction.

Content view

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var user = User()

@State var template: Template?
@State var category: Category?

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        List {
            
            Picker("Template", selection: $template, content: {
                ForEach(user.templates, id: \.self) { template in
                    Text(template.name)
                        .tag(template as Template?)
                }
            })
            .onChange(of: template, perform: { value in
                if template != nil {
                        category = template!.category
                        
                        print(category)
                    }
            })
            
            Picker("Category", selection: $category, content: {
                ForEach(user.categories, id: \.self) { category in
                    Text(category.name)
                        .tag(category as Category?)
                }
            })
            
            Button("Add") {
                template = nil
                category = nil
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

}

User struct

```
struct User: Codable, Hashable {
var templates = [Template()]
var categories = [Category()]
}
```

Template struct

```
struct Template: Codable, Hashable {
var name = "Test Template"
var category = Category()
}
```

Category struct

```
struct Category: Codable, Hashable {
var name = "Test Category"
}
```

Comment: Can you come up with a [mre]? Right now, I'd be concerned about `category as Category?` because it implies that your `selection` type isn't the same as your `tag` type, which will cause problems.

Comment: @jnpdx So the only it is like that is because `category` is initialized like this `@State var category: Category?`. If I didn't use `category as Category` the picker wouldn't select anything.

Comment: Okay. Like I said, a [mre] would help.

Comment: @jnpdx I added some code, which should reproduce the issue. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: @jnpdx disregard that code works as expected.

Comment: @jnpdx Yea I'm not sure what's going. That code is basically the same as what's in the app. In both instances, category will be set and will print data to the console, however, in the actual app it will not populate the picker but in that new code I posted it will.

Comment: Sounds like a good debugging project. One approach would be to replace what you have with your working example and then add back in the differences until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the issue was. When a transaction was added, the category would be updated to show that it has a new transaction. All it did was add to an `Int` variable, so the category would know how many transactions there are. Because that category was modified when a transaction was added, the template that used the category needed to be updated as well. I wasn't doing that previously. So I added some code to update the template with the updated category when a transaction was added, or deleted, and now the picker populates every time. Thanks @jnpdx for the help. Hopefully that makes sense.